# Error using massive of panels: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to try using several panels. But there is the error. When I click button_1, it should show one of the panel and hide another. I initialize my panels in Form_Load. Here is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Panel[] p = new Panel[2];
        public int iter = 1;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (iter%2 == 1)
            {
                p[0].Visible = true;
                p[1].Visible = false;
            }
            else if (iter%2 == 0)
            {
                p[0].Visible = false;
                p[1].Visible = true;            

            }
            iter++;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                p[i] = new Panel();
                p[i].Visible = false;
                p[i].Size = new Size(200, 100);
                p[i].Location = new Point(41, 103);
            }
            p[0].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            p[1].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have to add the panels to the main window.

Comment: It shouldn't throw exception in current form. There must be something else, are you sure that your `Form_Load` event is attached correctly and being called. Also make sure you are not doing `p = new Panel[2];` anywhere else in your code. Put a break point on `Form_Load` see if it gets hit and try stepping through the code

Comment: I didn't attack Form_Load manually. I just clicked twice on the form, and this method addes automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        p[i] = new Panel();
        p[i].Visible = false;
        p[i].Size = new Size(200, 100);
        p[i].Location = new Point(41, 103);
        this.Controls.Add(p[i]);   // You need this line to add panel to form
    }
    p[0].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    p[1].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
}
```

Comment: the error appears in this block:if (iter%2 == 1)
            {
                p[0].Visible = true;
                p[1].Visible = false;
            }

Comment: why p[0] and p[1] is null?

Comment: and it can't assign true or false to p[0].visible

Comment: Like Habib said, are you sure `Form1_Load` is being called? Set a breakpoint to be sure.

Comment: one more question: how to create one parent Panel, and then inharit his properties, just not to set same properties in cycle as I did?